# Geth private network problems generating ether

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, mining

## Short description

I have three Ethereum nodes connected in a private network and I am using the interactive Javascript console with geth.

The problem is, I cannot find a way to get ether on any of the accounts. The balance is always 0.

## Details

For all three nodes, the configuration and output are similar with the difference only in their addresses and account numbers.

File tree before running `geth`:

```
~/eth/
    database/
        keystore/
    genesis/
        CustomGenesis.json
```

Contents of `CustomGenesis.json`:

```
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 15,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0
  },
  "nonce": "0x0000000000000042",
  "timestamp": "0x00",
  "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "extraData": "0x00",
  "gasLimit": "0x08000000",
  "difficulty": "0x0400",
  "mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "coinbase": "0xd77821c8b92e3e29bc63c8f2a94a6c6a64b28b53",
  "alloc": {
    "0x862e90e6b6ebfe0535081d07be8e0f38e422932c": {"balance": "100"},
    "0x47e4cf0cc71e7257663f3d2f95e3f8982ece3ad8": {"balance": "200"},
    "0x1df2f4f40c03367a9bf42b28a090fed1cccb3068": {"balance": "300"},
    "0xd77821c8b92e3e29bc63c8f2a94a6c6a64b28b53": {"balance": "4444444444444444444"},
    "0x28685a4b9418c1cb85725318756aa815e8e34497": {"balance": "5555555555555555555"},
    "0x86f0526280fea57255c6391a4c7dbdbe8e1181ab": {"balance": "6666666666666666666"}
  }
}
```

While in the directory `~/eth/` I started `geth` with:

```
sudo geth --networkid 15 --datadir ./database --nodiscover --maxpeers 2 --rpc --rpcport 8080 --rpccorsdomain * --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --port 30303 --identity TestNet init ./genesis/CustomGenesis.json
```

... which produced the following output:

```
INFO [07-12|13:12:46] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.6.6-stable-10a45cb5/linux-amd64/go1.8.1
INFO [07-12|13:12:46] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/ethereum6/eth/database/geth/chaindata cache=128 handles=1024
INFO [07-12|13:12:46] Writing default main-net genesis block 
INFO [07-12|13:12:47] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 1 Homestead: 1150000 DAO: 1920000 DAOSupport: true EIP150: 2463000 EIP155: 2675000 EIP158: 2675000 Metropolis: 9223372036854775807 Engine: ethash}"
INFO [07-12|13:12:47] Disk storage enabled for ethash caches   dir=/home/ethereum6/eth/database/geth/ethash count=3
INFO [07-12|13:12:47] Disk storage enabled for ethash DAGs     dir=/home/ethereum6/.ethash                  count=2
WARN [07-12|13:12:47] Upgrading db log bloom bins 
INFO [07-12|13:12:47] Bloom-bin upgrade completed              elapsed=222.754µs
INFO [07-12|13:12:47] Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[63 62]" network=15
INFO [07-12|13:12:47] Loaded most recent local header          number=0 hash=d4e567…cb8fa3 td=17179869184
INFO [07-12|13:12:47] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0 hash=d4e567…cb8fa3 td=17179869184
INFO [07-12|13:12:47] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=0 hash=d4e567…cb8fa3 td=17179869184
INFO [07-12|13:12:47] Starting P2P networking 
INFO [07-12|13:12:47] HTTP endpoint opened: http://127.0.0.1:8080 
INFO [07-12|13:12:47] RLPx listener up                         self="enode://5ded12c388e755791590cfe848635c7bb47d3b007d21787993e0f6259933c78033fd6fa17cbb884ed772f1c90aebaccc64c5c88cddc1260e875ac8f6f07067bf@[::]:30303?discport=0"
INFO [07-12|13:12:47] IPC endpoint opened: /home/ethereum6/eth/database/geth.ipc
```

Interactive Javascript console is started in another terminal with:

```
sudo geth attach ipc:$HOME/eth/database/geth.ipc
```

... which gives:

```
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

instance: Geth/v1.6.6-stable-10a45cb5/linux-amd64/go1.8.1
coinbase: 0x1fb9fb0502cb57fb654b88dd2d24e19a0eb91540
at block: 0 (Thu, 01 Jan 1970 03:00:00 MSK)
 datadir: /home/ethereum6/eth/database
 modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0

>
```

Etherbase is set on all nodes with `miner.setEtherbase(personal.listAccounts[0])`. Each node only has one account. (3 nodes, 3 accounts)

```
> eth.accounts
["0x1fb9fb0502cb57fb654b88dd2d24e19a0eb91540"]
> personal.listAccounts
["0x1fb9fb0502cb57fb654b88dd2d24e19a0eb91540"]
>
```

Calling `admin.nodeInfo` gives:

```
> admin.nodeInfo
{
  enode: "enode://5ded12c388e755791590cfe848635c7bb47d3b007d21787993e0f6259933c78033fd6fa17cbb884ed772f1c90aebaccc64c5c88cddc1260e875ac8f6f07067bf@[::]:30303?discport=0",
  id: "5ded12c388e755791590cfe848635c7bb47d3b007d21787993e0f6259933c78033fd6fa17cbb884ed772f1c90aebaccc64c5c88cddc1260e875ac8f6f07067bf",
  ip: "::",
  listenAddr: "[::]:30303",
  name: "Geth/v1.6.6-stable-10a45cb5/linux-amd64/go1.8.1",
  ports: {
    discovery: 0,
    listener: 30303
  },
  protocols: {
    eth: {
      difficulty: 17179869184,
      genesis: "0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3",
      head: "0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3",
      network: 15
    }
  }
}
>
```

The nodes are connected with `admin.addPeer(..)` such that each node shows two peers when calling `admin.peers`.

When I start mining with `miner.start()`, this is the output that I receive in the interactive js console:

```
> miner.start()
null
>
```

... and in the other terminal running the node:

```
INFO [07-12|13:16:34] Updated mining threads                   threads=0
INFO [07-12|13:16:34] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=18000000000
INFO [07-12|13:16:34] Starting mining operation 
INFO [07-12|13:16:34] Commit new mining work                   number=1 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=749.279µs
```

After that nothing happens and the balance on all accounts is still 0 when checking with `eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0])`.

What options do I have to try and get the nodes on the private network to start mining ether?

Why does the preallocation of ether not work in `CustomGenesis.json`?

Was the difficulty provided in `CustomGenesis.json` ignored? `admin.nodeInfo` showed a different number.

All comments and suggestions are welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was apparently the way the genesis block was initialized.

### The Wrong Way

By calling `geth` with `init` and the other command-line arguments:

```
geth --networkid 15 --datadir ./database --nodiscover --maxpeers 2 --rpc --rpcport 8080 --rpccorsdomain * --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --port 30303 --identity TestNet init ./genesis/CustomGenesis.json
```

the node is started with the mainnet genesis block:

```
...
INFO [07-12|13:12:46] Writing default main-net genesis block
...
```

and after that, everything else cannot work the way expected.

### The Solution

Call `geth` with `init` and `--datadir` arguments only:

```
geth --datadir /path/to/database init /path/to/CustomGenesis.json
```

A short output is given and `geth` immediately exits when the initialization is finished:

```
INFO [07-13|10:30:49] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/path/to/database/geth/chaindata cache=16 handles=16
INFO [07-13|10:30:49] Writing custom genesis block 
INFO [07-13|10:30:49] Successfully wrote genesis state         database=chaindata                                   hash=ed4e11…f40ac3
INFO [07-13|10:30:49] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/path/to/database/geth/lightchaindata cache=16 handles=16
INFO [07-13|10:30:49] Writing custom genesis block 
INFO [07-13|10:30:49] Successfully wrote genesis state         database=lightchaindata                                   hash=ed4e11…f40ac3
```

and after this, everything else works as expected.

Big thanks to [Péter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8295306/) for helping me figure this out!

Answer (score 1):

You probably set the genesis difficulty so high, that your CPU miners don't have a chance of finding a block. You probably want to set the difficulty to something more reasonable, such as 1 million (`0x100000` in hex).

Comment: I edited the post to add details. Also the output after `miner.start()` has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll provide what input I have (bear in mind that I am new as well, so we are in the same boat!)

The part I am confident in, is the whole balance part, so: 
1. Make a new account (on whichever node): personal.newAccount("password")
2. Set the new account to be the coinbase of this node: miner.setEtherbase(eth.accounts[0])
3. Start the mining: miner.start()

Then, you can check the balance while you are mining. Try:
web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase), "ether")

Comment: This is correct yes, but the problem was currently elsewhere. Thanks anyway!